# Adding ROS install tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went through the process of building ROS Hydro from source on Debian and recorded to process for wiki material. I just created an account with the ros.org and it seems like I don't have the kind of privileges to go about making a new page. I had tried to edit yesterday and accidentally overwrote the install page, someone noticed it before I did and it has now been fixed. How do I add a page and link it to the Hydro experimental install section correctly, is this even how I should be contributing this material?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84816/adding-ros-install-tutorials/) by [St3am](https://answers.ros.org/users/6506/st3am/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That would be a great contribution.

To create a new wiki page, go to the URL while logged into the wiki and it will say "Page Not Found" but there is a link to "Create New Empty Page" which if you click will allow you to edit it.

For your convenience I commented back in the debian link on the [hydro Platforms page](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Platforms) Just put your tutorial where it links.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1